# When you hover over the sub-navs in sequence, the previous sub-navs remain, making it impossible to click on any of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have added setTimeout for 3 seconds in this hover functionality as per requirement now i am facing below issue while hovering over sub-navs:

-> When you hover over the sub-navs in sequence, the previous sub-navs remain, making it 
impossible to click on any of them.

Is there any way to remove this overlapping of sub-navs when you hover over new main navs? But still i want 3 second stopage when we remove mouse from main nav so that i can get time to select subnavs?

Example: http://design1.advisorproducts.com/home

Below is ths JQuery code:

```
$(function () {
    $("ul.dropdown li").hover(function () {
        var timeout = $(this).data("timeout");
        if(timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $('ul:first', this).css('visibility', 'visible');
    }, function () {
    $(this).data("timeout", setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
          $(this).removeClass("hover");
          $('ul:first', this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
      }, this), 600));
    });
    $("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append(" &raquo; ");
});
```

Comment: Add a blur event handler?

Comment: Is the requirement that there a lag before the sub-nav disappears (a neat but silly effect) or that the sub-nav disappears independent of any user action (forcing the user to re-hover if 6 seconds is not enough)? If it's the latter, why not just add a `.blur()` that also calls `removeClass("hover")` ?

Comment: Another downside to this approach appears to be cumulative, so if I run the pointer of the items back and forth 10 times, they all disappear after 6 seconds but won't reappear for 60 seconds.